# Optimize this SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

I am using MySQL DB. I have two tables -

1. Product_Data (it has some columns including PK productDataId)
2. Product_Data_Link(it has 5 columns Id(PK), productDataId(FK), LinkTypeId, IsActive, ProductDataLinkUrl)

I am running this query in one service call for multiple products. Is there any way to optimize it for fast execution.

```
select
    link1.ProductDataLinkUrl as ProductDataUrl1,
    link2.ProductDataLinkUrl as ProductDataUrl2,
    link3.ProductDataLinkUrl as ProductDataUrl3 ,
    link4.ProductDataLinkUrl as ProductDataUrl4 
FROM
    product_data pd 
left join
    product_data_links link1 
        on link1.ProductDataId = pd.ProductDataId 
        and link1.ProductDataLinkTypeId = 1 
        and link1.ProductDataLinkIsActive = 1 
left join
    product_data_links link2 
        on link2.ProductDataId = pd.ProductDataId 
        and link2.ProductDataLinkTypeId = 2 
        and link2.ProductDataLinkIsActive = 1 
left join
    product_data_links link3 
        on link3.ProductDataId = pd.ProductDataId 
        and link3.ProductDataLinkTypeId = 3 
        and link3.ProductDataLinkIsActive = 1 
left join
    product_data_links link4 
        on link4.ProductDataId = pd.ProductDataId 
        and link4.ProductDataLinkTypeId = 4 
        and link4.ProductDataLinkIsActive = 1 
WHERE
    pd.ProductDataId = 99999
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query should be fine with the following indexes:

- `product_data(ProductDataId)`
- `product_data_links(ProductDataId, ProductDataLinkTypeId, ProductDataLinkIsActive)`

Under some circumstances, it can be faster to use `group by`:

```
  select max(case when ProductDataLinkTypeId = 1 then ProductDataLinkUrl end) as ProductDataUrl1,
         max(case when ProductDataLinkTypeId = 2 then ProductDataLinkUrl end) as ProductDataUrl2,
         max(case when ProductDataLinkTypeId = 3 then ProductDataLinkUrl end) as ProductDataUrl3,
         max(case when ProductDataLinkTypeId = 4 then ProductDataLinkUrl end) as ProductDataUrl4
  from product_data_links pdl
  where ProductDataId = 99999 and
        ProductDataLinkIsActive = 1 and
        ProductDataLinkTypeId in (1, 2, 3, 4);
```

You want the second index above for this query.

Comment: Thanks. One of the index was missing now performance is bit better.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is important to add an index with the common related fields:  newIndex(ProductDataId, ProductDataLinkTypeId, ProductDataLinkIsActive, ProductDataLinkUrl)

Then, I like subqueries because the bring just the required field instead of bringing the full table with a join.

```
(select 
    (select l1.ProductDataLinkUrl from product_data_links l1 where l1.ProductDataId = pd.ProductDataId 
        and l1.ProductDataLinkTypeId = 1 
        and l1.ProductDataLinkIsActive = 1 ) as ProductDataUrl1, 

    (select l2.ProductDataLinkUrl from product_data_links l2 where l2.ProductDataId = pd.ProductDataId 
        and l2.ProductDataLinkTypeId = 2
        and l2.ProductDataLinkIsActive = 1 ) as ProductDataUrl2, 

    (select l3.ProductDataLinkUrl from product_data_links l3 where l3.ProductDataId = pd.ProductDataId 
        and l3.ProductDataLinkTypeId = 3 
        and l3.ProductDataLinkIsActive = 1 ) as ProductDataUrl3,

    (select l4.ProductDataLinkUrl from product_data_links l4 where l4.ProductDataId = pd.ProductDataId 
        and l4.ProductDataLinkTypeId = 4 
        and l4.ProductDataLinkIsActive = 1 ) as ProductDataUrl4
FROM
    product_data pd 
WHERE
    pd.ProductDataId = 99999)
```

I'll meassure times and result groups after each step of the refactor.

Good luck!